# Local Source Control

Tags: .net, visual-studio, version-control

Can anyone recommend a nice simple, easy to use source control system I can use locally on my laptop for a single user that integrates with VS2010? I am just looking for something that will let me do versioning locally and not particularly for collabrative working.

I have used SubVersion when part of a development team and that works very nicely with VS2010, but for my own personal projects/work I don't want to go to the hassle of installing SubVersion locally on my laptop just for myself.

I have tried Bazaar, but didn't really like it's distributed version control system and it's branches etc. Any other suggestions welcome. Thanks.

Comment: if you like subversion, installing it isn't much of a hassle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I will recommend you install [VisualSVN server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) on your local machine and run [Tortiose](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/) or [ANKHSvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/downloads) (open source) which will integrate with Visual Studio and provide all the version control that you need.

Comment: Replace "ANKHSvn" with "VisualSVN", and I completely agree :-)

Comment: @uwe-keim - Thanks for the reminder. I forgot that VisualSVN is a really good choice.

Comment: In my experience, AnkhSVN is much more stable now. It correctly handles all available source control operations, and even complex ones such as "new over deleted" etc. I switched to it from VisualSVN, even though my company was paying.

Answer (score 6):

I have personally found [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) extremely simple to pick up. Like Bazaar, it is a DVCS, but as a 1-man team this really doesn't have to change your workflow at all.

For Visual Studio integration, there's the [VisualHg](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) VS plugin, which uses [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Git and Mercurial are the two other main choices. The foremost being my preferred one.

http://book.git-scm.com/

It is quite easy and powerful. It supports branches, but do not force you to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want a local solution for versioning but the point to source control is to provide a point of contact OUTSIDE your system to store and backup source files(in the even your local system melts down, you have no where to go to get a backup). I have been using assembla's free svn repository with AhnkSVN in vs2010 and its been working out nicely.

Comment: It is not "the point" it is "a point". Other points of source control are history, branching, and code maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

The free [Perforce Server](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/downloads/index.html) supports 2 users - and is a breeze to set up.